# Java Scanner - Stop on last line

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I have a problem, in my program I want to read a .txt file with Scanner the txt file looks like:

```
10  2
20  3
30  5
40  6
750
```

I want to store each column in a `List` but the last row which is `750` to store separately in a `int` variable. I tried something like:

```
public class Testing {

    final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> readTextFile() throws IOException {

LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> finalT = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        int suma;
        List<Bancnota> bancnote = new ArrayList<Bancnota>();
        String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String finalPath = userHomeFolder + "/src/atm/TEST.txt";
        Path path = Paths.get(finalPath);

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path, ENCODING.name())) {

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String arr[] = line.split(" ");
             if (arr.length == 2){

                finalT.put(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.println(finalT);
         } else {

          suma = scanner.nextInt();      
               }  
             }
            scanner.close();
          }  
        return finalT;
    }
```

But something is not working, when I delete `750` from text file and delete this part

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String arr[] = line.split(" ");

          if (arr.length == 2){
```

everything is working. Is there any way to make the scanner to stop at last row? Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code with sensible indentation please?

Comment: @khelwood, I updated my question, this is all my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems here:

Your dataset `10  2`. These Numbers are separated by two spaces `" "`, so your `String.split` method will result in an array with three entries. `line.split(" ") -> {"10", "", "2"}` unless you you use `split("  ")`

Then you are using the `Scanner` wrong. You read a full line with `scanner.nextLine();` and then you are using `scanner.nextInt()` several times. But this will read the next number after the line you have already read.
I think you want to parse the Integers out of the line you have read.
So I think you want your lines

```
finalT.put(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt());
[...]
suma = scanner.nextInt();
```

to be something like this:

```
finalT.put(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
[...]
suma = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

change the while loop to below.

```
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String arr[] = line.split(" ");


            if (arr.length == 2) {

                finalT.put(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]),Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                System.out.println(finalT);
            } else {

                suma = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            }
        }
```